# What happens to American odds when the point spread gets further from zero?

Tags: probability, games, odds

I am learning about American odds ([moneyline odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-odds_betting#Moneyline_odds)) and point spreads. In Chapter 2 of *Sports Betting for Dummies*, I see:

> When the point spread on a game gets further from zero, the two moneyline bets get further apart. For example, they might move from -150 (on the favorite) and +135 (on the underdog) to -160 and +145.

I don't understand the example. From my intuition, when the point spread increases, the American odds (moneyline) on the favorite should increase (e.g. from -150 to -140 [and not decrease from -150 to -160 as in the example]). I don't see why anyone would accept a decreased potential profit when the probability of winning is decreased.

To give an extreme illustration, suppose the point spread increases from 0 to 1 quadrillion. To the best of my knowledge, no sports team has ever gained a 1 quadrillion point lead over their opponent, so a bet on the favorite will likely never win if there is a point spread of 1 quadrillion. Therefore, the moneyline on the favorite should **increase** (e.g. from -150 to +100000000000...).

Furthermore, I don't see how the first sentence is true:

> When the point spread on a game gets further from zero, the two moneyline bets get further apart.

From my intuition, if the point spread is increased to a level such that the bet on the favorite and the bet on the underdog have increasingly equal probability of winning, the two moneyline bets should get **closer together** (and not further apart). For example, if the point spread is $x$, and this $x$ point spread results in bets on both sides getting a $50\%$ probability of winning, their moneyline should be equal (e.g. -110 and -110). Therefore, when the point spread on a game gets further from zero, the two moneyline bets get **closer together before moving further apart**.

Am I wrong? If so, could you explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Is this question more suitable on other Stack Exchange sites? I feel that it contains more gambling vocabulary than one could reasonably expect from most statisticians.

Comment: You could perhaps edit in a glossary of terms. I suspect some of these are US specific as well as being gambling specific.

Comment: Cross-posted on the Sports Stack Exchange site: [What happens to American odds when the point spread gets further from zero?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/25178)